# Converting html page containing openlayers map to pdf via wkhtmltopdf

Tags: javascript, openlayers, wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf, wkhtmltopdf-binary

I have Html page contains tables and OpenLayers map
Everything works ok on all the browsers even IE.
I want to convert this page to pdf so I used wkhtmltopdf and as I read  wkhtmltopdf using behind the scene WebKit to render the page so I test the output on **Qt Web Browser** the browser refuses to display the OpenLayers map due to the error 
`ol-debug.js:18601ReferenceError: Can't find variable: requestAnimationFrame`

```
ol.PluggableMap.prototype.render = function() {
  if (this.animationDelayKey_ === undefined) {
    this.animationDelayKey_ = requestAnimationFrame(
        this.animationDelay_);
  }
};
```

because this error wkhtmltopdf convert only the Html tables and ignore the map

Ps: I use those command for converting

```
wkhtmltopdf.exe --enable-javascript --no-stop-slow-scripts --javascript-delay 2000 --debug-javascript
```

any idea or suggestion for a workaround for this issue

thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

I found out using Chrome headless is the better and fastest option in converting html to pdf

C:\Google\Chrome\Applicationchrome.exe --headless --disable-gpu --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw --virtual-time-budget=2000 --print-to-pdf=C:\newPdf.pdf https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/animation.html